# How to increase solr score for pattern start with

Tags: solr, lucene

Hi i wants to increase the score for document whose text should start with queried string. below is my sample data.

Search String (qf) : keyword_txt:"Hockey Jersey"

Edismax Boost (bq) : title_t:("Hockey Jersey")^100

sample response data link [JSON Response](https://gist.github.com/ajaypatelbardoli/d80bd46cbcb52bbd7ee8)

Now I wants to increase the score for those document whose title should start with "Hockey Jersey" how can i achive it?

Comment: Do you have any other fields to work with? Boosting by a prefix match on a TextField with a KeywordTokenizer and a lowercasefilter might work.

Comment: let me share you my schema file https://gist.github.com/ajaypatelbardoli/d73424048bdbec0a2a9e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to adjust the weights based on the values you see from debugQuery, but something like:

```
bq=title_t:("Hockey Jersey")^100 name:Hockey\ Jersey*^1000
```

.. would boost entries starting with Hockey Jersey ten times more than those who only have Hockey Jersey somewhere in their title.

Use `debugQuery=true` to see the weights assigned to each term.